# String to Integer Expressions

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, integer

I am trying to convert an expression given as a String into an Integer. For ex. if given "1+5*5" the method should return "26". I started writing the code only for solving a multiplication, however, when I run it there is not an output

```
  public static void operationS(ArrayList<String> m)  
{
    for (int i=0; i<m.size(); i++)
    {
        while ( (m.get(i)).contains("*"))
        {
            int x = ((m.get(i)).indexOf("*"));
            char A=((m.get(i)).charAt(x-1));
            char B= ((m.get(i)).charAt(x+1));

            int r= Character.getNumericValue(A)*Character.getNumericValue(B);

            String numberAsString = Integer.toString(r);

            if(x==1 && (m.get(i)).length()==3)
            {
                m.set(i, numberAsString);

            }

            if(x==1 && (m.get(i)).length()>3)
            {
            String n = numberAsString+((m.get(i)).substring(x+2));
            m.set(i, n);

            }

            else
            {
                String k= ((m.get(i)).substring(0,x-1))+numberAsString+((m.get(i)).substring(x+2));
            }

            }
        }
    for (int u=0;u<m.size();u++)
            {
            System.out.println (m.get(u));
            }
    }
```

Since I cannot import any libraries, my plan of action was replacing the String every time an operation was completed.

I plan on  using the same loop for adding, subtracting and dividing

Comment: I'm pretty sure you posted an exact duplicate earlier today... please don't repost exact same questions, it's discouraged and very frowned upon.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Please do some research on expression parsing.  Basically you'll need to go through the string from left to right, looking for _lexemes_ which are the numbers and operators in the expression, and working with them as they come up.  Searching for operators and trying to find the numbers next to them is most likely going to lead to grief when you end up doing operations in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider parsing your expression. You can probably use an Prefix, Infix, or Postfix notation and parsing to evaluate the input expression.

I came across an article that can help you in understanding how to achieve this:

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/SimpleParser/SimpleParser.html

The article basically talks about different approaches to solve this problem.

I personally liked the recursive approach. So if you understand recursion, you can choose that.

But if you have a requirement to use only a loop, you may prefer one of the other approaches.

> **Update**: Adding a sample piece of code implementing recursion based on the article linked above.

```
    static final char[] ops = { '-', '+', '*', '/'};

    static double evaluate(String s){
        for(char op: ops) {
            if(s.contains(String.valueOf(op))){
                String op1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(op));
                String op2 = s.substring(s.indexOf(op) + 1, s.length());
                switch(op) {
                    case '-': return evaluate(op1) - evaluate(op2);
                    case '+': return evaluate(op1) + evaluate(op2);
                    case '*': return evaluate(op1) * evaluate(op2);
                    case '/': return evaluate(op1) / evaluate(op2);
                }
            }
        }
        /* at this point there is no operator in the term anymore, just a number */
        return (convertToDouble(s));
    }

    private static double convertToDouble(String s) {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String replaceAll(CharSequence cseq, String regex, Function<MatchResult, String> replacement) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(cseq);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String replaced = replacement.apply(matcher.toMatchResult());
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replaced));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

static int toInt(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

And

```
String input = "1 + 5 * 5";
String output = input;
while (true) {
    String r = replaceAll(output, "(\\d+)\\s*\\*\\s*(\\d+)",
        m -> "" + (toInt(m.group(1)) * toInt(m.group(2))));
    if (r.equals(output)) break;
    output = r;
}
while (true) {
    String r = replaceAll(output, "(\\d+)\\s*\\+\\s*(\\d+)",
        m -> "" + (toInt(m.group(1)) + toInt(m.group(2))));
    if (r.equals(output)) break;
    output = r;
}
System.out.println(input + " -> " + output);
```

result:

```
1 + 5 * 5 -> 26
```